# Nagiosgrapth - no graphs

Tags: nagios

I have installed Nagiosgraph on my CentOS 7 with NGINX + PHP-FPM, manually, with this two HowTos:

http://sourceforge.net/p/nagiosgraph/git/ci/master/tree/INSTALL
http://sachinharma.blogspot.com/2013/08/nagiosgraph-graphs-in-nagios-on_7.html

All seems work - but I haven't any real graphs:

[image]

Please, pay attention - there is yellow rectangle - it's selected by mouse, and looks like - there is some "graph", but it won't display.

I have data in rrd directory:

```
# rrdtool dump /var/nagios/rrd/www.dev.domain.com/Current%20Load___load1.rrd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rrd SYSTEM "http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/rrdtool.dtd">
<!-- Round Robin Database Dump -->
<rrd>
        <version>0003</version>
        <step>300</step> <!-- Seconds -->
        <lastupdate>1435935645</lastupdate> <!-- 2015-07-03 15:00:45 UTC -->

        <ds>
                <name> data </name>
                <type> GAUGE </type>
                <minimal_heartbeat>600</minimal_heartbeat>
                <min>NaN</min>
                <max>NaN</max>
...
```

No error in logs, etc.

In `nagios.cfg`:

```
...
process_performance_data=1
service_perfdata_file=/var/log/nagios/perfdata.log
service_perfdata_file_template=$LASTSERVICECHECK$||$HOSTNAME$||$SERVICEDESC$||$SERVICEOUTPUT$||$SERVICEPERFDATA$
service_perfdata_file_mode=a
service_perfdata_file_processing_interval=30
service_perfdata_file_processing_command=process-service-graph
...
```

In `templates.cfg`:

```
define service {
       name graphed-service
       action_url show.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$' onMouseOver='showGraphPopup(this)' onMouseOut='hideGraphPopup()' rel='showgraph.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$&period=week&rrdopts=-w+450+-j
       register 0
     }
```

In `commands.cfg`:

```
define command {
       command_name  process-service-graph
       command_line  /bin/perl /usr/local/nagios/libexec/insert.pl
     }
```

And finally - in host config:

```
define service{
        use                             local-service,graphed-service
        host_name                       www.dev.domain.com
        service_description             Tomcat mem
        check_command                   check-tomcat-mem!8080!admin!Iivoh4pe
        notifications_enabled           1
        }
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in my `/opt/nagiosgraph/etc/nagiosgraph.conf`.

There was:

```
nagiosgraphcgiurl = /usr/local/nagios/sbin/
```

Instead of:

```
nagiosgraphcgiurl = /nagios/cgi-bin
```

This fixed my problem.